# vga connection with Ubuntu 12.04 32b problem

Tags: connection, vga

I want to connect my computer to my tv scree but my VGA connection on my computer doesn't work. There is no connection at all. Do I need to install drivers or something. Sorry I am new in Ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32bits on Macbook Pro core 2 duo T9300 2.50gh
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to install any drivers... you need to change the mode on TV.

Are you using Ubuntu?